# How much space does the Homebrew new installation take up?

Tags: macos, homebrew

This ought to be a really simple question, yet apart from the disparate "Receiving objects" line items that show up in the terminal installation (MacOS Big Sur), I'm not seeing anything about this online or from Homebrew itself. Most Google searches for "how much space does Homebrew take up" point me towards the "brew cleanup" command or questions asking about how important cellar space is.

I'm curious about how much disk space is taken from my computer *right after I've run the curl command on the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) website*.

From the GitHub, it looks like downloading and unpacking the zip gives me a folder of about 10mb in size -- this doesn't seem like the right size to me since the "receiving objects" lines quoted me at least 300mb of objects were being downloaded (although I don't know enough about git's download process to know what's going on here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an interesting question. I just did a exploration of my local homebrew installation.

```
$ du -h -d 2 .
4.0K    ./bin
 44K    ./completions/bash
104K    ./completions/zsh
132K    ./completions/fish
288K    ./completions
1.3G    ./Library/Taps
106M    ./Library/Homebrew
1.4G    ./Library
 32K    ./docs/vale-styles
236K    ./docs/assets
896K    ./docs
104K    ./manpages
 48K    ./.github/workflows
 12K    ./.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE
 76K    ./.github
 84M    ./.git/objects
 24K    ./.git/info
148K    ./.git/logs
 48K    ./.git/hooks
100K    ./.git/refs
 85M    ./.git
8.0K    ./.vscode
4.0K    ./.sublime
1.5G    .
```

As you can see, it mainly consists of two folders (Taps and Homebrew), one is the formula/cask stuff, the other one is the core Homebrew functionality.

The core homebrew only takes about 106MB space.

Answer (score 0):

On a new Monterey 12.6, I compared disk occupancy before and after Homebrew installation : Homebrew +3.0GB, brew install --cask xquartz +0.8GB. G'Day.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34973098)